# What is meant by a "triangular" system of linear equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, definition

My guess is a system such as :

$a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+...+a_{1n}x_n=b_1$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a_{22}x_2+...+a_{2n}x_n=b_2$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ...$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a_{mn}x_n=b_{m}$

i.e. a system $Ax=b$ where $A$ is upper triangular. Would we call the system triangular even if $A$ is lower triangular? I think we should.

Comment: By symmetry, there are also lower-triangular systems, with $A$ being lower-triangular. Just pass from $A$ to $A^T$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is an (upper) triangular system which can be obtained for any linear system by [Gauss elimination algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).